# Triple Integration problem, stuck.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have a doubt over this triple integral: I have to integrate

$$\iiint x\ \text{d}x$$

between

$$z = x^2 + y^2 ~~~~~~~ and ~~~~~~~ 4x + z = -2$$

But I feel like dumb because I cannot even start!

It's between $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $z = -4x - 2$.

If I equal them I get

$$x^2 + y^2 + 4x + 2 = 0$$

Which I cannot solve, if it makes sense.

**Cylindrical Try**

$$x = R\cos\theta ~~~~~ y = R\sin\theta$$

Then it is

$$z = R^2$$

$$4R\cos\theta + R^2 = -2$$

Which means

$$R = -2\cos\theta \pm \sqrt{2}\sqrt{2\cos^2\theta + 1}$$

Right?

**OR**

Without cylindrical coordinates, I can solve for $y$ and $x$.

$$y^2 = z - x^2$$
and using $z = -4x -2$ I find

$$y = \pm \sqrt{2 - (x+2)^2}$$

The same for $x$ finding

$$x = -2+\sqrt{2} ~~~~~ x = -2-\sqrt{2}$$

Then I have limits, right??

Comment: Try cylindrical coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{-2-\sqrt{2}}^{-2+\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\sqrt{2-(x+2)^2}}^{\sqrt{2-(x+2)^2}}\int_{-2-4x}^{x^2+y^2}x\,dzdydx$$
let $x=-2+r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$

Comment: Wow, so cool and fast!

Comment: So Thanks... :)

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you, but I didn't understand one thing. By what I have, I could find $y$ without cylindrical coordinates. It's enough to solve
$$y^2 = z - x^2$$

Using $z = -4x - 2$

Also I didn't get the $x$ extrema! >.<

Comment: Also I can find $x$ without cylindrical coordinates too!

Comment: $x^2+y^2=z=-2-4x$

Comment: $y^2=2-(x+2)^2$

Comment: Indeed! So why the cylindrical coordinates changing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41226/discussion-between-behrouz-maleki-and-time-master).